# generating quintiles and recoding multiple variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 33 columns/variables with different values. What I am trying to do: generate quintiles for all variables (done), then use the quintiles to recode each variable (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2) by quintile, I generated quintiles using:

```
q <- apply(ndataframe[2:34], 2, quantile, c(.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), na.rm = T)
```

Each variable is on different scale which is why the quintile values differ. I assume there is a better and more efficient way to then recode by quintile than what I have been doing so which is using the quintile values and manually recoding each column one by one, e.g.:

```
n_df_quins$A_q <- recode(n_dataframe$A
                   "0:1529 = '-2'; 1530:2199 = '-1'; 2200:2999 = '0'; 3000:3999 = '1'; 4000:25000 = '2'")
```

Thanks very much for any assistance anyone can offer.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what is in q?  maybe `head(q)`?

Comment: perhaps this? `cut(x, quantile(x, c(0,.2, .4, .6, .8, 1)), c(-2,-1, 0, 1, 2))`, and then use lapply to do it to all columns

Comment: Essentially, each column has a set of about 1000 observations and about 32,000 NAs (which refer to the other columns). For example: ColA: 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA; ColB: NA, NA, NA, 8, 4, 7, NA, NA, NA; ColC: NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 4, 3. Each column has same # of rows. I need to recode each column by quintile according to each column's values before then combining all the columns into one single column with the -2 to 2 scale. Sorry if this is a bit unclear. @G5W.

Comment: @Shape, I get teh following when I try the cut: Error in cut.default(x, quantile(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), na.rm = T),  : 
  'breaks' are not unique

Comment: Take a look at the output of `quantile(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)`.  you probably have enough repeated values that two of these are the same.

Comment: @tall_table hard to say, since I don't have your data, but G5W is almost certainly right. In that case, you need to clarify whether you want to assign -2 or -1 in those situations, which seems to suggest that the problem may be ill-posed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `percent_rank` and create a new data set with percentile values for each observation in each columns and then write a function to recode based on your criteria which you can apply on the whole data set in one go using `mutate_all`. Below is the code:

```
library("dplyr")
df<- data.frame(var1 = c(1:100), var2 = sample(1:1000, 100))
df1<- mutate_all(df, percent_rank)
recode_new<- function(x)
{
x = ifelse(x<=.2, -2, ifelse(x<=.4, -1, ifelse(x<=.6,0, ifelse(x<.8,1,2))))
return(x)
}
df_final<- mutate_all(df1, recode_new)
```

Let me know if you have any question

Comment: when I create the new data set, am I replacing var1 and var2 in code above with my actual first two variables?

Comment: I am not following you. Please elaborate.

Comment: confused about how to generate percentile values for each observation for each of my columns (the 2nd line of your code, "var = c(1:100), var2 = sample(1:1000, 100)." Conceptually it makes perfect sense, but how to adapt it to my data is where I am confused. Would it be: mydf <- data.frame(myoriginalvar1 = c(1:100), myoriginalvar2 = sample(1:1000, 100).  Or am I changing this according to the dimensions of my data set. thanks very much.

Comment: Ohh I see. The second line of code is not for generating percentile value. I am just creating a sample data set there. I am creating percentile rank in the third line of the code. And I am doing that using the function `mutate_all`, which applies the function `percent_rank` to all the columns. You can do the same using `df2<- data.frame(apply(df, 2, percent_rank))`. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: OK, got it. Worked like a charm. Much appreciated!